# Moving back to premise after migrating to Cloud-based DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We're currently investigating moving from on-premise DevOps to Cloud-based DevOps, there is sufficient migration information and processes, but what happens if we want to reverse it... bring it back in-house?

Is their a migration path for this?

Checked various websites and I cannot find anything that fits.

Comment: I will add that we are going to do a trial migration first, but management wants to know that if we migrate to Cloud and then months/years down the track, we decide to go back, how much work will it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Azure DevOps is constantly receiving updates and is almost always *ahead* of any available on-prem versions of Azure DevOps Server. You can't go backwards.